# Create a single video file from multiple video parts

Tags: java, c++, c, video, android-ndk

I want to **create a single video** file **from multiple video files**(parts). I have no. of files of  video types in format of (.mp4/.3gp) using them i want to create single video file with (.mp4/.3gp) extension. 
It will work as video clubbing application from smaller parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) is good choice for you. There are many manuals how to do that in the web. [Here's manual](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html) for using OpenCV with Android NDK.

Another option for you is to port some video processing library on Android. But it's very compicated.